# Creating buffer around line shapefile where buffer varies in size using ArcMap

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, shapefile, buffer

I have created a line shapefile which is representing a proposed pipeline route. Along this proposed pipeline is a trench running either side at different distances from the proposed pipeline (Pipeline is the black dashed line and buffer is the purple polygon.

[image]

I have set the buffer to be 50m either side of the Proposed pipeline but there are certain points where the trench is not uniform and is wider and narrower at places as seen from the picture below.

[image]

You can see the green line is the pipeline and the Purple dashed is the trench. this image shows areas where the trench is wide in some parts and narrower at others.

Is there a way to create a buffer around a line shapefile which will allow me to have varying buffer sizes using ArcMap?

Comment: You may cut the line and for each segment have a field with the buffer size, you can then use the buffer tool with this field as buffer size (as a side note a 100m wide trench seem extremely wide)

Comment: is there a tool which cuts the line into specific segments? and I am not sure of the exact trench width right now (more realistic to be 10m +/-) but used 100m as an example

Comment: For this, I would suggest to put points at every interval where your trench is wider (starts and endpoint). Have a look at the "Split Line at Point" tool in ArcGIS which can then cut the line into different segments.  You would then have to enter manually approx.  trench widths for every segment and as @J.R suggests use that field to calculate the buffer based on these segments.

Comment: Are you really using version 10.0 of ArcMap?

Comment: I have removed the tag, I am using Arc 10.6.1